# Better way to add/remove list items from a list in an unordered manner with Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a list of `<tr>`s and each `tr` contains some input tags.

I have a javascript function to add a new `tr` but each `tr` has its own delete button. So the user can delete a `tr` that's in the middle of the list.
`tr`s should be deleted in whatever order the user presses the delete button.

Currently, it seems working. See the code below.
It basically finds all the nodes which are subject to be deleted, removes events bound previously and rebinds a new event to keep track of which *n-th* node is clicked and thus must be deleted.

The `tr`s are also populated with a list of objects returned from the server using `<c:forEach>`

```
function addPressRelease(){
    var lastIndex = $(".pressRelease").length;
    console.log("lastIndex:"+lastIndex);
    var newIndex=lastIndex+1;
    var html = "<tr class='pressRelease' id='pr_"+newIndex+"'>";
    html+="<td class='rLine'><input type='text' name='pressArticleTitles' class='it'   style='width:260px;'/></td>";
    html+="<td>";
    html+="<input name='pressArticleLinks' type='text' class='it' style='width:495px;'/>";
    html+='<img class="delPr" src="/resources/00Publish/img/common/del.gif" alt="Delete" class="del buttonised" >';
    html+="</td>";
    html+="</tr>";
    console.log("appending..");
    $("#pressReleaseTable").append(html);

    reorganiseDynamicList("pressRelease", "delPr", "pr_");
}

function deletePressRelease(id){

    delNodeById(id);
    reorganiseDynamicList("pressRelease", "delPr", "pr_");
}

function reorganiseDynamicList(nodeClass, containerClass, nodePrefix){

    var nodes = $("."+nodeClass);

    $(nodes).each(function(index, element){

        $(element).prop("id", nodePrefix+index);

    });

    var containers = $("."+containerClass);

    $(containers).each(function(index, element){
        $(element).off();
        $(element).click(function(){
            delNodeById(nodePrefix+index)
        });

    });

}

function delNodeById(id){
    console.log("deleting node:"+id);
    $("#"+id).remove();
}
```

But I feel this could be inefficient and think maybe there is a better way, though the problem is, I can't think of any.

Is there a better way to do this ?

**Edit**

As suggested, I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13L0w1z6/1/) page. It was my first time using JSFiddle though. I hope this helps.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: You'd have better to delegate events to table level. Now provide MCVE if you wish someone to post more complete answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('body').on('click','.del',function(){

  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gxam0vdf/2/